# Google Sitemap HttpHandler cacheing

Tags: asp.net, caching, httphandler

I have a HttpHandler that generates a Google sitemap based on my asp.net web.sitemap. Fairly standard stuff. Except that it does some fairly heavy database work to auto-generate additional urls for Ajax tabs within pages.

All this means our DB gets hit fairly heavily if the bot hits sitemap.axd.

What we need, of course, is output caching. But how do you go about caching inside something that basically writes directly to a XmlTextWriter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest answer is to write the XML to a string and store it in a static field.

Comment: Okay two questions (1) Is that thread safe? (2) How do I get a string from a method that takes a XmlTextWriter... at the moment I'm creating the new XmlTextWriter(response.Output) so everything goes directly out to response.

Comment: Make a static method that returns a string, and call the method in the field's initializer.  That will be thread safe.

Comment: Make an `XmlTextWriter` around a new `StringWriter`, then call `StringWriter.ToString()`.

Comment: Darn the simplicity and my stupidity ;-) I've not done much with writers, can you tell!? Thanks!